# Is there any way to read text file and use words inside it as input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I'm dealing with one task where I have to read the text file and take every word present in it as input & the important thing is I should have to do it by using while or any other loop (Without making use of awk command)

I tried it with while loop it is reading the file but I'm not able to figure out the next steps.

Here are the details :

### Content File (Source File )

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat content.txt
Rantndeep,old spice,100,20
D-mart,toothbrush,30,20
more,sack,300,10
```

### Required Output

```
[root@localhost ~]# sh parser.sh
Today I went to Rantndeep Store bought old spice For Rs. 100 And paid 20 Rs.as a parking charges
Today I went to D-mart Store bought toothbrush For Rs. 30 And paid 20 Rs.as a parking charges
Today I went to more Store bought sack For Rs. 300 And paid 10 Rs.as a parking charges
```

### My Script

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat p.sh
#/bin/bash
cat content.txt | while read a
do
     echo $a
done
```

This is only printing the contents of a file as mentioned above I want to script it by using any loop so that I could get the output as

```
[root@localhost ~]# sh parser.sh
Today I went to Rantndeep Store bought old spice For Rs. 100 And paid 20 Rs.as a parking charges
Today I went to D-mart Store bought toothbrush For Rs. 30 And paid 20 Rs.as a parking charges
Today I went to more Store bought sack For Rs. 300 And paid 10 Rs.as a parking charges
```

Comment: Please wrap your all codes/samples in CODE TAGS.

Comment: can you please elaborate the thing I'm new to this world.

Comment: Kindly see this post once for your reference https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Comment: @SKuser : You also should defined what is a word. For instance, are `abc,def` and `x100` both one words, or two, respectively?

Comment: @SKuser : How about replacing `cat content.txt` by `fmt -1 content.txt`?

Comment: @ user1934428 Implemented :) .....Thanx all for your guidance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly at it. Note that you can use `read` to set more than one variable. Try

```
IFS=, # Because you separate the items using comma instead of space
while read w1 w2 w3 w4
do
  echo "first word: $w1  second word: $w2  last word: $w4"
done < content.txt
```

you will see that on each iteration, `w1`... `w4` contain the 4 fields of the respective line in content.txt

Comment: Please quote your strings. Perhaps one day you read a variable `*` of `$(rm *)`.

Comment: @WalterA : The _rm_ wouldn't harm, because the echo would still not execute the code. The `*` argument is valid. I have updated my answer accordingly. Since I usually work with Zsh, I always forget that we need that lot of quoting when doing bash. One of the reasons why I don't like bash so much.

Comment: @ user1934428 can you help me with my another question please check my profile